# SQL Tables: Store references to an unknown number of rows in table A in a single record in table B

Tags: sql

I have a table of People, and a table of Service Tickets. Service Tickets refer to 1+ People, and over time People are likely to be associated with multiple Tickets. What is the best way to represent this relationship in a SQL database?

It seems like my two options are to create 'enough' columns to contain all the person id's i should need, or a single huge string column that is processed CSV style after being fetched from the database. Both of these options have a maximum capacity, which seems like a bad design, and the second design means we can't join using the person id's.

A little background - I'm implementing a fairly small database as part of the backend for a class project. I've never really worked with SQL and what I know is self taught.

I feel like this is has to be a duplicate question, but I'm unable to find anything similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if this si a MANY to MANY relation ship, creat the table accordingly.

Create a table, something like

```
PeopleServiceLink:
PersonID,
ServieTicketID,
PRIMARY KEY (PersonID, ServieTicketID)
```

Have a read hear at [Understanding SQL: Many to Many Relationships](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx)

Comment: +1 for explicitly identifying the compound PK, this helped me understand why this third table would be useful where the other answers did not.

Answer (score 2):

For many-to-many relationship generally create three tables: Tickets(id, ...), People(id,...) and join table like TicketsPeopleJoin(ticketId, peopleId)

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate `tickets_people` table which has `person_id` & `ticket_id` columns.